# Kotlin composition of coroutine context inside constructor of coroutine scope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What exactly is this code doing?

```
private val supervisorJob = SupervisorJob()
protected val presenterScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + supervisorJob)
```

What is the result of `Dispatchers.Main + supervisorJob`? I understand it must be some sort of composition but how does it work? And how is it called?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a lot of questions.

> What exactly is this code doing?

You can look at this as follows: this code creates a new `CoroutineScope`, with dispatcher set to `Main` and and behaviour set to `SupervisorJob`

`Dispatchers.Main` means that the coroutine will execute on the main thread. Usually this refers to Android UI thread.

`SupervisorJob` means that unlike regular `Job` behaviour, when failure of one of the children will also fail the parent, and all the other children too, the job will just continue as usual.

> What is the result of Dispatchers.Main + supervisorJob?

The result is `CoroutineContext`. You can think of it as a hash map of different keyed values.

> I understand it must be some sort of composition but how does it work?

You are correct. If you look at `CoroutineContext` implementation, you'll see that it implements `operator fun plus`, which allows to use `+` to combine two objects of type `CoroutineContext`

> And how is it called?

Usually coroutine methods are extension methods on `CoroutineScope`. If we look at `async()`, for example:

```
public fun <T> CoroutineScope.async(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
): Deferred<T>
```